# Selecting multiple ranges subject to a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to select multiple ranges subject to each range meeting a set criteria?

For example, if I have 12 ranges in excel, I only want to select the range to be included if the range contains data

If range 1 & 3 have data and range 2 does not have data i want to select Range(1,3) excluding range 2

Can this be done with vba code for excel

Comment: Do you literally mean to select these ranges? You can use the `CTL` and selection if that's what you mean... or do you mean to be included in like a summation or something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it very well. I have some code that selects multiple ranges for printing out, I want to adjust the code so that it only prints the ranges that have data and excludes the ranges that have no data

Comment: Range("zone1,zone2, zone3, zone4, zone5, zone6, zone7, zone8, zone9, zone10, zone11, zone12").Select

  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")

Comment: Are the ranges in the same worksheet? Could you share a few range addresses so we can actually test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the Union function.

This code would go through a range of cells shown in the Range parameter and then select only those that are not empty.

```
Sub selectSomes()

Dim aCell As Range, zRange As Range

For Each aCell In Range("A5:J5").Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(aCell) Then
        If zRange Is Nothing Then
            Set zRange = aCell
        Else
            Set zRange = Union(zRange, aCell)
        End If
    End If
Next aCell

zRange.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can get it to work, appreciate your help. I looked at union but didn't understand how to structure it. I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck already. I have 12 names ranges that are reasonably large, I have a cell that checks if the ranges have data or not. If the named ranges have data I want to select all the named ranges ready to print (excluding those that do not have data)

Comment: How do i share a file, i have an example i can share

Answer (score 1):

### Select Non-Blank Ranges

- If at least one cell is not blank, the range will be 'added'.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SelectNonBlankRanges()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Union(ws.Range("Zone1"), ws.Range("Zone2"), ws.Range("Zone3"), _
        ws.Range("Zone4"), ws.Range("Zone5"), ws.Range("Zone6"), _
        ws.Range("Zone7"), ws.Range("Zone8"), ws.Range("Zone9"), _
        ws.Range("Zone10"), ws.Range("Zone11"), ws.Range("Zone12"))
     
    Dim prg As Range
    Dim arg As Range
    
    ' Combine the non-blank ranges into a multi-range.
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        'Debug.Print arg.Address, Application.CountBlank(arg), arg.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountBlank(arg) < arg.Cells.Count Then
            If prg Is Nothing Then
                Set prg = arg
            Else
                Set prg = Union(prg, arg)
            End If
        End If
    Next arg
    
    If prg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ws.Activate
    prg.Select
    
    MsgBox "Range '" & prg.Address(0, 0) & "' selected.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, I am still building that into my code, is there a way of just referencing a single cell for eth check rather than the full range. the range has some cells that always have data in them. ie each range has a heading that I want to print with the range?

Comment: Worked it out, I used the trigger I put into the sheet to blank the headings, all the range is blank now and your formula works perfectly. Thanks for sharing your fantastic knowledge, very clever.

Comment: Nearly got it, it is seeing the formula in the cell and hence is not blank. Any ideas of how to change the count?

Comment: @DarrenFletcher, You have a rating of 33, which means you should know that StackOverflow is about asking a *single clear question* and accepting an answer to that question. VBasic put a ton of work into answering your question (way more than me). Asking each of us random follow-up questions such as deciphering blank cells or how to share a file, without accepting an answer is poor etiquette. Give him an ✔ , and then ask for more free information.

Comment: got it, thanks for your help

Comment: ahh didn't know about the tick

Comment: @Darren Fletcher: Related to *is there a way of just referencing a single cell*: you need to explain what the common identifier of this cell(s) in all those ranges is, e.g. the last cell is blank, the first cell in the second row is blank, all cells in the last column are blank, the cell before the last cell in the second row is blank,... Note that I already know that *each range has a heading*. This information is needed to successfully 'build' the `If` statement.